# How to use Y.Notify.Message?

Tags: javascript, notifications, yui, notify, yui3

I have a problem with http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/notify

Unfortunately I'm using the older version of YUI (3.4.0) so it's even harder to search for the solutions. I can't change it so I have to stick to it :(

I have read documentation page a couple of times, but I still can't figure out how to use **flag**. It says it's a part of configuration of Y.Notify.Message, but how do I access it? There is no example on the site except a very simple way of using Y.Notify constructor.

I was trying something like that:

```
notification.add({
    message  : 'Some message',
    flag     : 'some_flag',
    timeout  : 1000,
});
```

Unfortunately it does nothing ...

Any help will be appreciated, because I'm leaning to some 3rd-party library more and more... Still I would rather use something that is part of the framework I use.

The funniest part is I have checked the source code on the github:
https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery/blob/master/src/gallery-notify/js/notify.js

...and I don't see any **flag** there :(

However have I found one here:
https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery/blob/master/src/gallery-notify/js/notify.js~

What is the current version? Anyone?

I also checked the github repository for https://github.com/apipkin/xarno/blob/master/src/gallery-xarno-notify/js/notify.js which should be the most recent version of the code and it also has no **flag**.

Thanks a million!

Comment: YUI seems to have a lot of documentation vs code inconsistencies

Comment: I'll get the code updated as soon as I can. Thanks for the notice of the bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. You should contact the author.

A workaround to add a class for skinning would be to create the message as a widget first, add your class and then pass it to Y.Notify:

```
var message = new Y.Notify.Message({
  message: 'Some message',
  timeout: 1000
});
message.get('boundingBox').addClass('my-skin-class');
notification.add(message);
```

Another option would be to add it as an object to the notification widget and then retrieve it using `item(index)`:

```
notification.add({
  message: 'Some message',
  timeout: 1000
});
notification.item(notification.size() - 1).get('boundingBox').addClass('my-skin-class');
```

Comment: I'm using 'gallery-notify' module (in YUI 3.4.0). Y.Notify has no Message class: "TypeError: Y.Notify.Message is not a constructor". Maybe I'm using a wrong module?

Comment: Which Gallery build are you using?

Comment: My YUI.Env.versions says that 'gallery-notify' is version 'gallery-2011.03.11-23-49'. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Any time you use a Gallery module you should specify the build using something like `YUI({gallery: 'gallery-2013.06.13-01-19'}).use(...)`. The Gallery page for each module shows the latest build tag for that module.

Comment: Each YUI build is stamped with the latest gallery tag at that moment. Using a gallery tag is only needed if you are using a gallery tag newer than the YUI version you are using.

Comment: I guess that is the case in my situation. I will try a newer build of gallery.